# Translating ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
function getCategory($year){
  if(!$year){
      $year=2017;
  }

  $q = $this->msdb->query("SELECT category_code, COUNT(*) AS numb
                          FROM easypm_sales_orders WHERE YEAR(sales_date) = $year
                          GROUP BY category_code ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC");
  return $q->result();
}
```

So, I have this model function and I want to translate the SQL query bit into codeigniter. I tried:

```
function getCategory($year){
        if(!$year){
            $year=2017;
        }

        $this->db->select('category_code');
        $this->db->count("* as 'numb'");
        $this->db->from('easypm_sales_orders');
        $this->db->where('YEAR(sales_date)', $year);
        $this->db->group_by('category_code');
        $q = $this->db->order_by('numb', 'desc');

        return $q->result();
    }
```

but no luck, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$q = $this->db->order_by('COUNT(*)', 'DESC');`  did you face any problem in this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select("category_code, count(*) AS numb",false)
    ->from ("easypm_sales_orders")
    ->where("YEAR(sales_date)",$year)
    ->group_by("category_code")
    ->order_by("numb","DESC")
    ->get();

return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is necessary to use `DB::raw()` to represent a `WHERE` clause involving a function of a database column.  Also, while it *is* possible to get a count from a Laravel query without using `DB::raw()`, if you want to assign a custom alias to that count it is also needed here.  Consider the following code:

```
$this->db->select(DB::raw('count(*) as numb, category_code'))
$this->db->from('easypm_sales_orders');
$this->db->whereRaw('YEAR(sales_date) = ?', $year);
$this->db->group_by('category_code');
$q = $this->db->order_by('numb', 'desc');

return $q->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter active record has no `count` method.
only `count_all_results` and `count_all` and [they are used differently](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)
You need replace your select options like this and remove `$this->db->count("* as 'numb'");`

```
$this->db->select('category_code');
$this->db->select('COUNT(*) numb');
```

Rest of your code OK.